# Regex string: specific requirement

Tags: regex

I am trying to get my regex string right but I don't seem to get it working as it should.

I have a numeric field that should have 5 digits.
The digits can start only with `04xxx` and `5xxxx`

This string is not covering it completly:

```
/[05][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```

it forces to start with 0 or 5 followed by 4 digits, but it allows for example `012345`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try this for your regex pattern:

```
^(04|5\d)\d{3}$
```

Comment: It's better to use anchors. Note that `should have 5 digits`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I agree. Just thought I'd keep in line with his original pattern, which was anchor-free.

Comment: only `matches` method does this thing, is there any?

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a validation -

`^(?=04|5)\d{5}$`

Expanded:

```
 ^               # BOS
 (?= 04 | 5 )    # Lookahead, starts with '04' or '5'
 \d{5}           # Match 5 digits
 $               # EOS
```